# how to make headless chrome to work using protractor for window authentication pop up

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor, single-sign-on, google-chrome-headless

I want to support window authentication pop up for login to the application using Protractor using chrome headless browser. Is there any way in which I can make it work?

I have already tried:

1. Chrome authentication extensions - https://www.npmjs.com/package/authenticator-browser-extension
2. Loading URL in the below format: 
   http://username:password@url.com which did not work out.